# How to retrieve Global address list using SAS

Tags: outlook, sas

Is there any way to extract Outlook Global address list details using SAS. I would need Associate details and his manager email address. Please assist

We have VBA code in place and it is talking more time to pull details, But we would like to migrate it to SAS

We have only VBA code and it is too lengthy

```
    Private Const xlUp As Long = -4162
Sub CopyGALToExcel()
'This is an Outlook Macro
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olGAL As Outlook.AddressList
Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntries
Dim olMember As Outlook.AddressEntry
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olGAL = olNS.GetGlobalAddressList()
'the path of the workbook
strPath = "MyDrive\Vikas.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
'clear all current entries
xlSheet.Cells.Select
xlApp.Selection.ClearContents
'set and format headings in the worksheet:
xlSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "OutLastName"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "OutFirstName"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "OutWorkPhone"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = "OutEmail"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 5).Value = "OutTitle"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 6).Value = "OutDepartment"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = "EmployeeID"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 8).Value = "ManagerID"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 9).Value = "OutOfficeLocation"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value = "OutCompanyName"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 11).Value = "OutAddress"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 12).Value = "OutCity"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 13).Value = "OutAddressEntryUserType"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 14).Value = "OutApplication"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 15).Value = "OutAssistantName"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 16).Value = "OutClass"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 17).Value = "OutComments"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 18).Value = "OutDisplayType"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 19).Value = "OutID"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 20).Value = "OutMobilePhone"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 21).Value = "OutLastFirst"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 22).Value = "OutParent"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 23).Value = "OutPostalCode"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 24).Value = "OutPrimarySmtpAddress"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 25).Value = "OutPropertyAccessor"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 26).Value = "OutSession"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 27).Value = "OutStateOrProvince"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 28).Value = "OutStreetAddress"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 29).Value = "OutType"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 30).Value = "OutYomiCompanyName"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 31).Value = "OutYomiDepartment"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 32).Value = "OutYomiDisplayName"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 33).Value = "OutYomiFirstName"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 34).Value = "OutYomiLastName"
End With
Set olEntry = olGAL.AddressEntries
On Error Resume Next
'first row of entries
j = 2
' loop through dist list and extract members
For i = 1 To olEntry.Count
    Set olMember = olEntry.Item(i)
    If olMember.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
        If olMember.GetExchangeUser.Department <> "" And olMember.GetExchangeUser.LastName <> "" And olMember.GetExchangeUser.FirstName <> "" Then
                'add to worksheet
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.LastName
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.FirstName
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 3).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 4).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 5).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.JobTitle
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 6).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Department
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 7).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Alias
                If IsNull(olMember.Manager.Alias) Or olMember.Manager.Alias = "" Then
                    strMgrID = GetOutlookInfoFromGWID(olMember.GetExchangeUser.Alias, "ManagerId")
                    If IsNull(strMgrID) Or strMgrID = "" Or strMgrID = "Not Found" Then
                        xlSheet.Cells(j, 8).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.GetExchangeUserManager.Alias
                    Else
                        xlSheet.Cells(j, 8).Value = strMgrID
                    End If
                Else
                    xlSheet.Cells(j, 8).Value = olMember.Manager.Alias
                End If
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 9).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.OfficeLocation
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 10).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.CompanyName
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 11).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Address
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 12).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.City
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 13).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.AddressEntryUserType
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 14).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Application
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 15).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.AssistantName
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 16).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Class
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 17).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Comments
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 18).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.DisplayType
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 19).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.ID
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 20).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.MobileTelephoneNumber
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 21).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Name
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 22).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Parent
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 23).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.PostalCode
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 24).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 25).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.PropertyAccessor
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 26).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Session
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 27).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.StateOrProvince
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 28).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.StreetAddress
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 29).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Type
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 30).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.YomiCompanyName
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 31).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.YomiDepartment
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 32).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.YomiDisplayName
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 33).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.YomiFirstName
                xlSheet.Cells(j, 34).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.YomiLastName
                j = j + 1
            Else
                j = j
            End If
 GetOutlookInfoFromGWID(strGWID As String, strInfo As String)
 Dim outApp As Object 'Application
   Dim outTI As Object 'TaskItem
   Dim outRec As Object 'Recipient
   Dim outAL As Object 'AddressList
    Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set outAL = outApp.Session.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
    Set outTI = outApp.CreateItem(3)
    outTI.Assign
    Set outRec = outTI.Recipients.Add(strGWID)
    outRec.Resolve
    If outRec.Resolved Then
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Select Case strInfo
            Case "Name"
                'GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = outRec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.name
                GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = outRec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.FirstName & " " & outRec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.LastName
            Case "Phone"
                GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = outRec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber
            Case "Email"
                GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = outRec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
            Case "ManagerId"
                GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = outAL.AddressEntries(outRec.AddressEntry.Manager.Name).GetExchangeUser.Alias
            Case "ManagerName"
                GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = outRec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Manager.Name
            Case "ManagerProperties"
                'GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = outAL.AddressEntries(outRec.AddressEntry.Manager.name).GetExchangeUser.Alias
            Case Else
ErrorHandler:
                 GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = "x"
            Resume Next
        End Select
    Else
        GetOutlookInfoFromGWID = "Not Found"
    End If
End Function
```

Please help is there any way to get above details.

Comment: What have you done so far to extract the data using VBA? What have you tried using SAS? Can you post sample code from both VBA and SAS, if applicable?

Comment: I haven't tried anything in SAS...I need help retrieving those Data using SAS.

Comment: Please find my VBA code below

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is not use Outlook for this operation. Outlook is a client tool to display information. In a company, this information normally comes from Active Directory which is a variant of LDAP. Hence, treat the address book as a database and ignore Outlook.

For code that reads that database, look at the following code:

```
   %let LDAPServer = "ADC21039.ms.ds.ABC.com";
   %let LDAPPort   = 389;
   %let BaseDN = "CN=Users,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=ABC,DC=com";
   %let BindUserDN = "CN=achurc1,CN=Users,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=ABC,DC=com";
   %let BindUserPW = "PASSWORD";
   %let Filter = "(objectClass=person)";
   %let Attrs=  "cn sn";

data _null_;

    length entryname $200 attrName $100 value $100 filter $110;

    rc =0; handle =0;

    server=&LDAPServer;
    port=&LDAPPort;
    base=&BaseDN;
    bindDN=&BindUserDN;
    Pw=&BindUserPW;

    /* open connection to LDAP server */
    call ldaps_open(handle, server, port, base, bindDn, Pw, rc);
    if rc ne 0 then do;
       put "LDAPS_OPEN call failed.";
       msg = sysmsg();
       put rc= / msg;
    end;
    else
       put "LDAPS_OPEN call successful.";

    shandle=0;
    num=0;

    filter=&Filter;

    /* search and return attributes for objects */

    attrs=&Attrs;

    /* search the LDAP directory */
    call ldaps_search(handle,shandle,filter, attrs, num, rc);
    if rc ne 0 then do;
       put "LDAPS_SEARCH call failed.";
       msg = sysmsg();
       put rc= / msg;
    end;
    else do;
       put " ";
       put "LDAPS_SEARCH call successful.";
       put "Num entries returned is " num;
       put " ";
    end;

    do eIndex = 1 to num;
      numAttrs=0;
      entryname='';

      /* retrieve each entry name and number of attributes */
     call ldaps_entry(shandle, eIndex, entryname, numAttrs, rc);
     if rc ne 0 then do;
         put "LDAPS_ENTRY call failed.";
         msg = sysmsg();
         put rc= / msg;
      end;
      else do;
         put "  ";
         put "LDAPS_ENTRY call successful.";
         put "Num attributes returned is " numAttrs;
      end;

      /* for each attribute, retrieve name and values */
      do aIndex = 1 to numAttrs;
        attrName='';
        numValues=0;
        call ldaps_attrName(shandle, eIndex, aIndex, attrName, numValues, rc);
        if rc ne 0 then do;
           msg = sysmsg();
           put rc= / msg;
        end;
       else do;
           put "  ";
           put "  ATTRIBUTE name : " attrName;
           put "  NUM values returned : " numValues;
        end;

        do vIndex = 1 to numValues;
          call ldaps_attrValue(shandle, eIndex, aIndex, vIndex, value, rc);
          if rc ne 0 then do;
             msg = sysmsg();
             put rc= / msg;
          end;
          else do;
             put "  Value : " value;        
          output;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;


    /* free search resources */
    put /;
    call ldaps_free(shandle,rc);
    if rc ne 0 then do;
       put "LDAPS_FREE call failed.";
       msg = sysmsg();
       put rc= / msg;
    end;
    else
       put "LDAPS_FREE call successful.";

  /* close connection to LDAP server */
    put /;
    call ldaps_close(handle,rc);
    if rc ne 0 then do;
       put "LDAPS_CLOSE call failed.";
       msg = sysmsg();
       put rc= / msg;
    end;
    else
       put "LDAPS_CLOSE call successful.";
run;
```

Comment: Here is a sample LDAP server you can test with until you are comfortable. Then try and access your AD server:

http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/